# Why's wrong with this template? how can I compile it correctly

Tags: c++

```
#include "test.h"
template<typename T>
test<T>::test(const T &elem):data(elem)
{
}

template<typename T>
test<T>::~test()
{
    delete data;
}
template<typename T>
class test
{
private:
    T data;
public:
    test(const T &elem);
    ~test();
};
#include"test.h"
int main()
{
    test<int> a(2);
}
```

Classes and implementations and main functions are written in different files by me, when i try to compile it ,The compiler will report an error,but i can't find what's wrong.

Comment: Are you getting undefined references?

Comment: Well, what does the error say?

Comment: You can't `delete data` when `data` is type `int`

Comment: I have written the definition and implementation of the template in separate files and imported definition with a header file

Comment: "_The compiler will report an error,but i can't find what's wrong._" Hint: when asking about compiler errors, consider providing said compiler errors in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your destructor as written:

```
template<typename T>
test<T>::~test()
{
    delete data;
}
```

assumes that `data` is a pointer. As it is declared having type `T` this means you cannot instantiate it with type `int` probably `int *` is the closest, but then your constructor does not make much sense. You probably want to remove `delete` statement from destructor, but it is difficult to say without seeing the whole picture.

Comment: although I delate my destructor,the compiler also says errors like:LNK2019 and LNK1120. What dose that mean?

Comment: @chris_piglet That mean error codes, but I am not a robot I read error messages in plain language

Comment: Do I have any other errors besides the constructor?

Comment: @chris_piglet Yes — read the duplicate question that is linked in the big, blue post notice above.

Comment: thanks, my friends. Learning c++ is a real challenge

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use the `delete` call in your destructor, your class member should almost always be type `T*`. However, having a member of type T is based on your use-case, and if you do, that member has memory allocated based on how you instantiate your class (calling `new()` and having it on the heap, or on the stack as you have). In this scenario, deleting the member T also happens when you call `delete()` on your instantiated class object, or is removed automatically from the stack when your object goes out of scope.

Comment: OK you gotta tell me how you managed to post an answer to a closed question.

Comment: That's my superpower :P